# Tkinter create a hidden frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI whose window will consists of a few frames.
I need to pack many different widgets in each frame so if all are shown it will occupy a lot of space.
The idea is that each frame will be revealed/hidden with the push of a button.

I'm able to hide and reveal each frame using buttons, however I'd like those frame to start as hidden.

Is there a way to do that?

Here's a code that hides/reveals the frames.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

import os

# Method to make Label(Widget) invisible
def hide_frame(frame):
    # This will remove the widget
    frame.grid_remove()
    
# Method to make Label(widget) visible
def show_frame(frame):
    # This will recover the widget
    frame.grid()
    
#____________________________________________________________________________________________   
#This will be the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
window.title("daq")

#____________________________________________________________________________________________
#Upper frame
frame_logo = Frame(window)    

#____________________________________________________________________________________________
#Lower frame
frame_main = Frame(window)
frame_main.place(rely=0.10, relx=0.0, relwidth=1.0)

#Create a tabcontrol
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(frame_main)
tabControl.grid(column=0, row=1)

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#Digitizer tab
tab_Digitizer    = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab_Digitizer, text='   Digitizer   ')
digitizer_tab_dummy_label = Label(tab_Digitizer, text="")
digitizer_tab_dummy_label.grid(column=0, row=0)   


#General board settings

lbl_general_board_registers = Label(tab_Digitizer,
                                    text="General board registers",
                                    font='bold')
lbl_general_board_registers.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)

frame_general_board_registers = Frame(tab_Digitizer)
frame_general_board_registers.grid(column=0, row=2)

btn_hide_general_board_registers = Button(tab_Digitizer, text="Hide", fg="red", command=lambda: hide_frame(frame_general_board_registers) )
btn_hide_general_board_registers.grid(column=1, row=1)


btn_show_general_board_registers = Button(tab_Digitizer, text="Show", fg="green", command=lambda: show_frame(frame_general_board_registers))
btn_show_general_board_registers.grid(column=2, row=1)   

lbl_threshold1 = Label(frame_general_board_registers, text="Threshold1")
lbl_threshold1.grid(column=1, row=0)

lbl_trigger1 = Label(frame_general_board_registers, text="Trigger1")
lbl_trigger1.grid(column=1, row=1)

#Channel settings

lbl_channel_registers = Label(tab_Digitizer,
                                    text="Channel registers",
                                    font='bold')
lbl_channel_registers.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)

frame_channel_registers = Frame(tab_Digitizer)
frame_channel_registers.grid(column=0, row=4)

btn_hide_channel_registers = Button(tab_Digitizer, text="Hide", fg="red", command=lambda: hide_frame(frame_channel_registers) )
btn_hide_channel_registers.grid(column=1, row=3)


btn_show_channel_registers = Button(tab_Digitizer, text="Show", fg="green", command=lambda: show_frame(frame_channel_registers))
btn_show_channel_registers.grid(column=2, row=3)

lbl_threshold = Label(frame_channel_registers, text="Threshold")
lbl_threshold.grid(column=1, row=0)

lbl_trigger = Label(frame_channel_registers, text="Trigger")
lbl_trigger.grid(column=1, row=1)


#Misc settings

lbl_misc_registers = Label(tab_Digitizer,
                                    text="Misc settings",
                                    font='bold')
lbl_misc_registers.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=W)

frame_misc_registers = Frame(tab_Digitizer)
frame_misc_registers.grid(column=0, row=6)

#_________________________________________________________________________________________________
tab_SignalViewer = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab_SignalViewer, text='   Signal Viewer   ')


#tabControl.grid(column=0, row=1)


#This keeps the window open - has to be at the end
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: dont pack/(grid/place) them in the first place?

Comment: @Thanos why are you packing or gridding them in the first place if you want them to start as hidden?

Comment: @Matiiss: Thanks for the comment. I never thought about that! Thanks! I had to modify a bit the `show` function, but it really simple!

Comment: @OmidKi Indeed! It's as simple as that! thanks!